# Пролог-эпилог функций Си

Tags: c, ассемблер, c++

Столкнулся с оптимизацией кода (Си, очень ограниченное количество памяти).  Для обработки прерываний используются функции с атрибутом _ *naked* _, который (по документации) подавляет генерацию пролога и эпилога функции. Раньше никогда не задумывался над этим. Можете пояснить зачем это? И в чем вообще суть пролога-эпилога?

Comment: 1. Есть ответ на stackoverflow
2. MS Visual C/C++? Странный выбор инструмента в данном случае...

Comment: Про stackowerflow не совсем понял.
Компилятор GCC. Все вещи с атрибутами, насколько я понимаю зависят от конкретной реализации компилятора?

Comment: Да, зависят от компилятора. Например, gcc __attribute__ ((naked)) поддерживается только для ARM процессоров.

Comment: AVR/AVR32 тоже, как я успел понять

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030977/what-does-vc-c-naked-attribute-do

Comment: И ещё, из gcc.info: 
`naked'
     Use this attribute on the ARM, AVR, IP2K and SPU ports to indicate
     that the specified function does not need prologue/epilogue
     sequences generated by the compiler.  It is up to the programmer
     to provide these sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пролог сохраняет контекст исполнения - те данные (флаги, регистры процессора и т.п.), которые могут быть изменены вызываемой функцией. А эпилог восстанавливает контекст, используя сохраненные данные.

При обработке прерываний требуется высокая скорость работы и код часто пишется на ассемблере (в том числе встроенном), и в этом случае можно самостоятельно сохранять и восстанавливать контекст (или не сохранять и не восстанавливать его вообще), не пользуясь возможностями компилятора.

Еще по теме: [пролог и эпилог](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tawsa7cb(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивный ответ!